# Writing $\exp{tA}$ as finite sum

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-exponential

Let $A \in \mathcal{M}_{n\times n} (\mathbb{R})$ such that $A^2=\alpha A$ for some $\alpha \neq 0$.

Under this assumption, we have by induction that $A^{n}=\alpha^{n-1}A$; $n \geq2$; then:

$$\exp(tA)=I+ tA+\frac{t^2A^2}{2!}+ \dots \ =I+At+\frac{A\alpha t^2}{2!} + \frac{A\alpha^2 t^3}{3!} + \dots = \\ = I+ \frac{1}{\alpha}A(1+ \alpha t+ \frac{\alpha^2 t^2}{2!} +\dots)-  \frac{A}{\alpha}=I+\frac{1}{\alpha}A\exp({\alpha t})- \frac{A}{\alpha}=I+A(\frac{\exp(\alpha t)-1}{\alpha})
$$

Are these steps correct?

Comment: I would say yes they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.- It is known that the function $x\to e^x$ **operates** over the algebra $\mathcal{M}_{n\times n} (\mathbb{R})$ (*I don't know how the french word **opère** is translated in the English of Functional Analysis World*). In simplest English, if $A\in\mathcal{M}_{n\times n} (\mathbb{R})$, the matrix $e^A\in\mathcal{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$

Now $\exp(tA)=I+A\left(\dfrac{\exp(a t)-1}{a}\right)$  is true each time that $A=aI$ in whose case $\exp(tA)=\exp(at)I$.

Is it possible that $A\ne aI$, say $A=aI+B$ for some non-zero $B\in\mathcal{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$?. From $A^2=aA$
we can get
$A=aI$ only if $A$ is not a divisor of zero.

I tend to believe with @Somos above that the equality is true but I rather feel more comfortable not answering the question for now.

Comment: Posting an answer to say you're not posting an answer...?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: What do you want, sir?  My last two lines clearly say that I share the opinion of the MSE Somos member, but I have (not now but I won't answer why) my doubts about it.